# Proving $(\frac{\ln x}{x})^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{x^{n+1}}(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I have to prove that:

$$
\Big(\frac{\ln x}{x}\Big)^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{x^{n+1}}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln x\Big)
$$

What I've got:

Using induction assuming it's true for some $n \in \mathbf N$ let us see what happens with $n+1$.

$$\Big(\frac{\ln x}{x}\Big)^{(n+1)}=\Big(\Big(\frac{\ln x}{x}\Big)'\Big)^{(n)}=\Big(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\Big)^{(n)}=\\
=\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}-\frac{\ln x}{x^2}^{(n)}
$$

OK, about $\frac{\ln x}{x^2}^{(n)}$, I know what $\frac{\ln x}{x}^{(n)}$ equals to from the inductive hypothesis. I was thinking about letting $u=x^2$ so that the second term becomes $ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln u}{u})^{(n)} $, but after $n$ differentiations becomes a mess.

Is there a way to deal with $\frac{\ln x}{x^2}^{(n)}$, knowing by the inductive hypothesis what $\frac{\ln x}{x}^{(n)}$ is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-complicating it:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)^{(n+1)}&=&\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)^{(n)}\\&=&\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{x^{n+1}}\left(H_n-\log x\right)\right]\\&=&\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}\left(H_n-\log x\right)-\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{x^{n+2}}\\&=&\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}\left(H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}-\log x\right)\\&=&\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}\left(H_{n+1}-\log x\right)\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}\end{eqnarray*} $$

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping the derivatives in the wrong order when you say $f^{(n+1)}=(f')^{(n)}$.  It should be $f^{(n+1)}=(f^{(n)})'$ instead. That gives

$$\left(\ln x\over x\right)^{(n+1)}=\left(\left(\ln x\over x\right)^{(n)} \right)'=\left({(-1)^{n-1}n!\over x^{n+1}}\left(1+{1\over2}+\cdots+{1\over n}-\ln x \right) \right)'$$

Can you take it from there?